# Measure without sets of measure zero

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite $\sigma$-additive measure space such that 
$$
E\in\Sigma,\quad\mu(E)=0\implies E=\varnothing
$$
Is it true that $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is purely atomic? You may assume that $\mu$ is complete.

I think I know how to prove this via Maharam theorem, but that looks like an overkill. I wonder if there is a simpler proof or maybe my guess is even wrong?

Comment: It seems to me the only part of Maharam you really need is that $X$ can be written as the union of a purely atomic space and an atomless space, and unless I am missing something, the proof of this is elementary. You don't need to characterize the structure of the atomless part.  And then it's easy to show that an atomless measure space with your property is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $x\in X$ it's easy to show that $x\in E_x\in\Sigma$ with $$\mu(E_x)=\inf\{\mu(E): x\in E\in\Sigma\}.$$Now $x\in E_x$ shows that $\mu(E_x)>0$.

And $E_x$ is an atom: Suppose $A\subset E_x$ and $\mu(A)>0$. If $x\in E_x\setminus A$ then $\mu(E_x\setminus A)<\mu(E_x)$ contradicts the minimality of $\mu(E_x)$. So $x\in A$; now again the choice of $E_x$ shows that $\mu(A)=\mu(E_x)$; so $\mu(E_x\setminus A)=0$, hence $E_x\setminus A=\emptyset$, or $A=E_x$.

So $X$ is the union of atoms, and it's clear that the set of atoms is countable.

Quiz Question: Where did we use the fact that $\mu$ is finite?

Comment: Why $\{x\}$ is measurable?

Comment: @Norbert Good question. See edit...

Comment: As far as I can see $E_x$ is a set where the infimum is attained. Is that correct?

Comment: @Norbert That's exactly what $\mu(E_x)=\inf\{\mu(E): x\in E\in\Sigma\}$ says...